# "But I guess we just have to take life as it comes, ___ we?" Should i use won't or don't?

Tags: grammar

I have a question about whether I should use *won't* or *don't* in the blank space and why?

> But I guess we just have to take life as it comes, ___ we?

I know that *won't* is used for future but I'm not sure.

Comment: Partly depends on what was said up to this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need "don't" here for concordance with the present tense in the first clause.

"We'll just have to take things as they come, won't we?" uses the future tense.

Comment: Nonsense. That's perfectly grammatical. First, there is no future tense in English; Second, the _don't_ is, as noted, concordant with the initial _have to_,so it's fine with a tag question; but so are several negative modal auxiliaries like _won't or shouldn't._ That's the way it usually works out; one adds options, as a rule, rather than subtracting them.

Comment: @john Lawler, you can and should quibble with my answer, but please don't leave poor teo in the lurch!  He asked an either-or question, and as best I can tell you answered, "Yes."  You point out several possibilities that could work (I guess), but he didn't ask about ways how to say the opposite of what he's trying to say. ***  Please hit me up in Chat to explain why you say English has no future tense.

Comment: Since  _won't_ is just another negative modal auxiliary, of course it's correct, like the others,